# calling a jar contains java and python classes, but path problem while python execution

Tags: java, python, jar

I have a maven java project. It contains python file and calls (using PythonInterpreter) then, return the result back to java class.

I have to deliver my project as a jar file. And they will call methods in my java class, my java class will execute my python code and later jar calling project will get result from java class.

I created a test project calling my jar pretending I have their java project. But it doesn't work. It is searching my python class inside the test project.

I am calling my python class inside main project using this:

```
interpreter.execfile("./src/main/java/deneme.py");
```

When I call my method from test project:

```
int a = JythonExampleStatic.denemeSumMethodStatic(34, 1);
```

My test project return this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" IOError: (2, 'File not found - 
C:\\Users\\user.name\\eclipse-workspace\\test.project.artifact\\.\\src\\main\\java\\deneme.py (python path I called inside main project) 
(The system cannot find the file specified)')
```

Note that my python class will never be callable from outside of project scope, it is just for execution.

How should I call my python class?
or
Where should I make a change?

```
|- mainProject
|   |-- src
|   |-- |-- main
|   |-- |-- |-- java
|   |-- |-- |-- | -- MyClassCallingPython.java (using PythonInterpreter)
|   |-- |-- |-- resources
|   |-- |-- |-- | -- MyPython.py


|- testProject
|   |-- src
|   |-- |-- main
|   |-- |-- |-- java
|   |-- |-- |-- |-- MethodCallsMyClassCallingPython.java
|   |-- |-- |-- ReferencedLibraries
|   |-- |-- |-- |-- mainProject.jar
```

Comment: You first need to learn about [the Standard Directory Layout](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html) and where your runtime classpath actually is. Nothing in `src` should be considered available at runtime, even if it happens to work in your IDE.

Comment: haha oh may be I couldn't express myself in a correct way, I will deliver my main project contains both java and python class as a jar. Therefore, I simulate their project as test. My problem is not related writing unit test.

Comment: Try `interpreter.execfile("src/main/java/deneme.py");` instead of `interpreter.execfile("./src/main/java/deneme.py");` by removing just the `./` at the beginning!!

Comment: Hi @Anwarvic, I tried your advice as a first trial, but this time it give error without dot: Exception in thread "main" IOError: (2, 'File not found - 
C:\\Users\\user.name\\eclipse-workspace\\test.project.artifact\\src\\main\\java\\deneme.py (python path I called inside main project) 
(The system cannot find the file specified)')

Comment: Could you tell me where is the `eclipse-workspace` located on your hard-disk??

Comment: Omg! it is already writing there C:\\Users\\myfirstname.mysecondname\\eclipse-workspace